# How to write this test case?

Tags: testcase

I have never worked as a QA but have some interest in the field and I received a task for an entry position which requires me to write a test case to fulfil this requirement (it's a messaging service):

1.Every person can have unlimited conversations and unlimited messages in a
conversation.

There were a few other specifications which were simpler and I followed the test case, test scenario, expected results format of writing them, but I am unsure how would one test if something works for unlimited amount of data, in this case, infinite messages?

Comment: It is quite obvious this requirement can never be obtained by a realistic system, no matter how big. Test-Case: More messages than particles in the universe - will not be possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Every person can have unlimited conversations and unlimited messages
>    in a conversation.

These are two use cases:

1. Every person can have unlimited conversations
2. Every conversation can have unlimited messages.

As one of the testing principle is :

**Exhaustive testing is not possible** .meaning you cannot test all the possibility for a system as the combination would be extremely large.

So in this case (infinite) is a uncountable and unachievable use case, **what you can do as a quality enthusiast is to.**

1. Understand your userbase. See what is the **average number of conversation kept in the app by your user**. Say you figured out that on an average users will keep only last 100 conversations. ( If there is no average see what is the maximum conversation kept  eg: User b had 10000 conversation which is the largest ever reported )
2. Understand your userbase. See what is the **average number of messages per conversation** kept in the app by your user. Say you figured out that on an average users will keep only last 100 messages per conversation. ( If there is no average see what is the maximum message kept  eg: User b had 10000 message in a conversation which is the largest ever reported )
3. Now test n*2 times messages and conversation , **where n is the max message or conversation.**
4. **Most important:** Each time **create new n*2** message and conversation  , don't clear old messages and converstaions. This gives you ever growing database which you can validate for ( near to infinite usecase) .

**Update:**

You can also choose to add N*2 messages to more than 1 conversation , say first 5 conversation ever added. This ensures that system works fine even when there are multiple conversations with ever growing near to infinite messages

Comment: Things like message conversations tend to have very long-tailed distributions.  Most of the time you might get just get two or three messages in a conversation, and then you'll have an outlier with two or three hundred.

Comment: @Mark how does it change the test approach mentioned could you elaborate

Comment: My point is that you don't get anything useful from looking at the average.  If the average conversation thread has 35 messages, but there's an outlier conversation with 107,416 messages, you need to test the 107,416-message case; doing anything with the 35-message case tells you nothing.

Comment: @Mark yes mark i agree  (I mentioned that in the answer use the maximum )

Comment: Thank you for the input, it's very helpful to understand how to deal with such a scenario. I have one question in regards to point 4. Do you create a new n*2 using the result of the old n*2, thus realistically making it n*4, or do you test it only once the old N max values have been surpassed?

Comment: @Tisho You can create new n*2 each time ( so you get ever growing conversation ) and always add ( n*2 ) message to all the new messages + add n*2 message to a static message say ( The first converstion ever added )

Comment: so that the first coverstaion you added will ahve ever growing message , and remaining will have n * 2. You can also choose to add N*2 messages to more than 1 conversation , say first 5 conversation ever added. This ensures that system works fine even when there are multiple conversations with ever growing near to infinite messages.

Comment: But what exactly do you mean by creating new n*2 every time? Since n is my maximum amount of messages ever recorded which might not change at all, does this mean that for the second calculation I will be using n*2 as my new n? So let’s say my initial n is 10. N*2 on first test will equal 20. Would second test be using 20 as my new N and the following calculation will be 20^2=40 and so on till infinity? It’s possible I’m not grasping fully the logic behind your explanation so I’m sorry if that’s happening, it’s just a new topic alltogether for me.

Comment: @Tisho n will always be 10 , so first you will have 20 conversation , on the next cycle you will  add again 20 more , so now the server has 40 conversation , again on next you will add 20 new conversation so total becomes 60 , and so on

Answer (score 5):

> unlimited conversations and unlimited messages

> something works for an unlimited amount of data, in this case, infinite messages

These two statements may mean different things.

There is no such thing as an infinite number of entities in a computer system because computers have physical limitations, in terms of memory, storage, processing.

What you can do is to create [testing charters](https://www.tricentis.com/blog/creating-an-exploratory-testing-charter/) detailing how you can explore these limitations.

For instance,

> Explore the application
> with the phone XYZ
> To discover how it handles keeping an extreme number of message loaded

Or

> Explore the backend service
> to discover how it behaves when an extreme number of messages are stored for a single user

Then during your exploration, you will use your skills to try to force the target to these extreme conditions. Later you debrief the people who need this information so they can make decisions.

Test cases are good documentation for situations where you know what you want to know. You have a specific routine and a known expected result.

This is called checking. Testing is an open-ended performance to discover facts we don't know. Testing is exploration. ([More about Testing versus Checking here](https://www.developsense.com/blog/2009/08/testing-vs-checking/))

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

I see this as a question which should introduce [performance / stress tests](https://www.guru99.com/performance-vs-load-vs-stress-testing.html) to determine the number of conversations / messages which still allows user to use the application and number of conversations / messages which the system can actually handle.

Comment: I see. In the case I don't have a report from current users, as suggested here by @PDHide, what number should I base my testing off or would the stress test involve incremental increase in messages/conversations count until the system can't handle it anymore?

Comment: You could estimate an upper bound by estimating your user-base and how much messages a user could produce in a certain amount of time. For example: **IF** a user has to type each message by hand, he will usually not be able to create more than 10 messages per second. So if the service is running 10 years, with a million users you will have `10*3600*24*365*10` messages per user and this number times a million for overall messages as a (vastly overestimated) upper bound.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will take try and implement this logic to the best of my knowledge. A bit of a side note question regarding test cases - is it acceptable to create a test case without test data, for example if I'm testing if X player can start a new conversation only if he has Premium package? There isn't a test data, as the steps include simply clicking the button "Message Now". In my mind, I need only a precondition that's being a Premium account available for testing.